# How to model operations in Scala that are only applicable to the same concrete implementations of a trait?

Tags: scala

## The Context

I am trying to build a small business rules application for the mobility sector, and specifically I am modelling `Filters` that are responsible to decide if a certain trip matches a given `Filter` configuration. Another invariant is that `Filters` of the same type are not allowed to *overlap* (what *overlap* means is then defined per concrete filter).

### The `Filter` trait

The `Filter` trait itself is pretty simple, it just defines a method to get the identifier for this filter. It also acts as a marker for higher level abstractions that only deal with general `Filters`

```
sealed trait Filter {
  def identifier: String
}
```

### The `CanOverlap` trait

#### UPDATE 1

Incorporated the changes from Brian's answer, but this also doesn't compile from the usage example below. Updated also the compiler error message.

#### UPDATE 1 END

This trait provides the public API `overlapsWith` that checks if two filters are overlapping. It does that by first checking if the two filters have the same type using the final and private method `isSameType`, and only if that is the case then it delegates to the abstract protected method `hasOverlapWith` which is then provided by the implementations.

```
sealed trait CanOverlap extends Filter {

  type This >: this.type <: CanOverlap

  final def overlapsWith(other: This): Boolean =
    isSameType(this, other) && hasOverlapWith(other)

  protected def hasOverlapWith(other: This): Boolean

  final private def isSameType[U, P](left: U, right: P)(
    implicit ev: U =:= P = null
  ): Boolean = ev != null
}
```

## Two example implementations

The following two examples should illustrate how the abstractions are implemented.

### DaysBeforeDeparture

```
final case class DayOfWeek(days: Set[java.time.DayOfWeek]) extends CanOverlap {

  type This = DayOfWeek

  protected def hasOverlapWith(other: DayOfWeek): Boolean = 
    days.intersect(other.days).nonEmpty

  def identifier: String = "day_of_week"
}
```

### DayOfWeek

```
final case class DaysBeforeDeparture(lower: Int, higher: Int) extends CanOverlap {

  type This = DaysBeforeDeparture

  protected def hasOverlapWith(other: DaysBeforeDeparture): Boolean =
    lower <= other.higher && other.lower >= higher

  def identifier: String = "days_before_departure"
}
```

## The question

**Is there a *simpler* way to achieve the same behaviour?**

Especially the `isSameType` method in the `CanOverlap` trait looks like a pretty *hacky* solution to me, and I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to deal with the *only run an operation if two instances are of the same concrete subtype*.

Kind regards and thanks in advance!

#### EDIT 1

So Brian's answer already got a me a bit forward, but maybe I was not explicit enough. so here is an additional example for the intended usage:

```
import java.time

val dowMondayTuesday = DayOfWeek(Set(time.DayOfWeek.MONDAY, time.DayOfWeek.TUESDAY))
val dowWednesdayFriday = DayOfWeek(Set(time.DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY, time.DayOfWeek.FRIDAY))
val dowTuesdaySaturday = DayOfWeek(Set(time.DayOfWeek.TUESDAY, time.DayOfWeek.SATURDAY))

val dbdThreeFive = DaysBeforeDeparture(3, 5)
val dbdOneTwo = DaysBeforeDeparture(1, 2)
val dbdTwoFour = DaysBeforeDeparture(2, 4)

val filters : Set[CanOverlap] = Set(dowMondayTuesday, dbdOneTwo)

filters.exists(_.overlapsWith(dbdThreeFive)) // Should return false
filters.exists(_.overlapsWith(dbdTwoFour)) // Should return true - (2, 4) overlaps with (3, 5)

filters.exists(_.overlapsWith(dowWednesdayFriday)) // Should return false
filters.exists(_.overlapsWith(dowTuesdaySaturday)) // Should return true - Tuesday overlaps
```

This now gives the following compilation error when run from a IntelliJ worksheet:

```
Error:(15, 106) type mismatch;
 found   : A$A0.this.dbdThreeFive.type (with underlying type com.flixbus.pricing.rules.model.Filters.DaysBeforeDeparture)
 required: x$1.This
def get$$instance$$res0 = /* ###worksheet### generated $$end$$ */ println(filters.exists(_.overlapsWith(dbdThreeFive)));//
                                                                                                        ^
```

Comment: I don't understand how any of your forall calls should return true. Maybe you meant to use `.exists`? Also, I don't understand how `DaysBeforeDeparture(2, 4).right.get` works, given the code you've provided.

Comment: Yeah, you are absolutely right concerning `.exists`. The `.right.get` was a copy and paste mistake because I am having some smart constructors in the companion objects for the filters that I left out for brevity. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Side note: I think your implementation of `DaysBeforeDeparture#hasOverlapWith` should be `lower <= other.higher && other.lower <= higher`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Runtime approach

The biggest problem is that, based on your usage example, you need a runtime solution, but `=:=` is a compile-time solution. Fortunately, you can use pattern matching and `ClassTag` instead.

```
sealed abstract class CanOverlap[This <: CanOverlap[This] : ClassTag] extends Filter {
  final def overlapsWith[T <: CanOverlap[T]](other: T) = other match {
    case t: This => hasOverlapWith(t)
    case _ => false
  }

  protected def hasOverlapWith(other: This): Boolean
}
```

This should be sufficient to solve your problem. Read on for some discussion of other options.

---

In that example, I changed `CanOverlap` to an abstract class so I could use a context bound. If you want, you can keep it a trait and use an abstract type, but it requires more boilerplate both here and in subclasses:

```
sealed trait CanOverlap extends Filter {
  type This >: this.type <: CanOverlap
  implicit val cls: ClassTag[This]
  ...
```

This has the advantages that `CanOverlap` is a trait and doesn't require type parameters, and that `This` has a lower bound. You may like it if you expect users to refer to `CanOverlap` a lot or if you have reasons for wanting it to be a trait. However, it requires subclasses to explicitly provide `cls`, so you may prefer the first approach if you have a lot of subclasses.

There is one more approach that gets rid of both kinds of boilerplate by shoving it into another class: have `CanOverlap` be a trait and `AbstractCanOverlap` be an abstract class extending it, using a context bound so that subclasses don't have to explicitly provide the ClassTag. This is sort of like how Scala has [`AbstractSeq`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/AbstractSeq.html) to handle the boilerplate shared between `Seq` implementations. Ultimately, it's a question of where you want to put the boilerplate.

#### Old answer (compile-time approach)

Your edit has made it clear to me that this won't work for you, but I'll leave it because it might help other people.

First, your `isSameType` method does not work. This is because `this` has type `CanOverlap[This]` which is potentially different from `This`, so this returns `false`:

```
DaysBeforeDeparture(1, 1).overlapsWith(DaysBeforeDeparture(1, 1))
```

However, I don't really think you need `isSameType` at all. I think your generic-based approach works, but could benefit from a little improvement. Here's my approach, based on [a gist by Odersky](https://gist.github.com/odersky/56323c309a186cffe9af).

```
sealed trait CanOverlap extends Filter {
  type This >: this.type <: CanOverlap

  def overlapsWith(other: This): Boolean
}
```

The most significant differences are that `This` is an abstract type instead of a type parameter and that I've added `this.type` as a lower bound. Now, let's try it out:

```
final case class DaysBeforeDeparture(lower: Int, higher: Int)
    extends CanOverlap {
  type This = DaysBeforeDeparture

  def overlapsWith(other: This): Boolean =
    lower <= other.higher && other.lower >= higher

  def identifier: String = "days_before_departure"
}

final case class DayOfWeek(days: Set[java.time.DayOfWeek])
    extends CanOverlap {
  type This = DayOfWeek

  def overlapsWith(other: This): Boolean =
    days.intersect(other.days).nonEmpty

  def identifier: String = "day_of_week"
}

DaysBeforeDeparture(1, 1).overlapsWith(DaysBeforeDeparture(1, 1)) // Compiles
DaysBeforeDeparture(1, 1).overlapsWith(DayOfWeek(Set())) // Does not compile
```

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for the pointer to `type This >: this.type <: CanOverlap`, but I think I was not explicit enough in my question. The trick should be that comparing different subtypes *should* be possible, but just basically *ignore* (read return false) the other implementations. I updated the question with a more explicit example of the usage.

Comment: Hey Brian, thanks for pointing out that there might not be a compile time solution for this problem. I tried looking for one since I somehow always feel "dirty" with reflection runtime checks. But your solution is elegant enough and gets the job done. Thanks for bearing with me :)